# How can I launch Visual Studio's "track changeset" window from PowerShell or another command line?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-power-tools

I have a lot of branches and changesets that are moving around, and to track them, I have to manually click on each changeset, track, etc. and it's really time consuming.

I'm trying to figure out a way to call the visualization window with arguments and just get the produced output.

[image]

[image]

I'm using VSTS, but I'd imagine the same applies to TFS.

I've looked at VSTS CLI (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/?view=vsts-cli-latest) and TFS PowerTools but so far nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

For TFVC repo hosted in VSTS, you can not tracking changeset by VSTS cli or TFVC commands.

For TFVC repo hosted in TFS, there has no way to tracking changeset by TFS power tool neither.

Comment: I have a TFVC repo hosted in VSTS. Is there anyway to automate changeset tracking? I just want to run some commands and dump out the a PDF/JPG of the changesets so I can see if we forgot to forward/reverse integrate anything. Can I build a VS extension somehow to interface with it?

Comment: @AlexKwitny No, there is no way to track changeset automatically. And if you want to build with your own extension, you should also calculate the relations among the changesets by yourself (as the extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterRJoseph.ChangesetViewer).